Find a condition that makes this differential equation homogeneous
Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be non zero real numbers. Consider the differential equation
$$x’ = t^{\gamma - 1} H\left(\frac{x^\beta}{t^\alpha}\right)$$
where $H : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.
Determine a condition on $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ that allows the proposed equation to be transformed into a homogeneous equation.
At first, I tried using one of the definitions of a homogeneous differential equation:
A first order ODE $x’ = f(t,x)$ is said to be homogeneous if $f(t,x)$ is a homogeneous function of degree $0$. That is,
$$f(\lambda t, \lambda x) = f(t,x)$$
Therefore, the problem consists in finding a condition on $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that
$$(\lambda t)^{\gamma - 1} H\left( \frac{(\lambda x)^{\beta}}{(\lambda t)^{\alpha}} \right) = t^{\gamma - 1} H\left(\frac{x^\beta}{t^\alpha}\right)$$
After doing some algerba, you get to this condition
$$\alpha = \beta \gamma$$
However, my solution was not accepted. I then tried solving the equation with a substitution of $y = \dfrac{x^\beta}{t^\alpha}$ but got stuck when solving the new equation given by
$$y’ = \beta t^{\gamma - \frac{\alpha}{\beta}} H(y)y^{1-\frac{1}{\beta}} - \frac{\alpha}{t}y$$
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

I guess we need to specify which equation transformations are allowed.

It is just dimensional analysis: $x,t$ must have the same dimensions.
It depends on $H$. Without any assumptions on $H$ (take for example $H=\exp$). Dimensionally, this means it takes in a dimensionless argument and spits out a dimensionless result. You then you only have the obvious solution:
$$
\gamma=1 \quad \alpha=\beta
$$
By absorbing $H(u^\alpha) = \tilde H(u)$, you can reduce to the case $\alpha=\beta=1$.
If $H$ is of degree $r$, then you get the equation:
$$
\gamma-1+r(\alpha-\beta) = 0
$$
You can therefore take any $\alpha,\beta$ and set:
$$
\gamma = 1+r(\beta-\alpha)
$$
